# groupby to count and after leftjoin

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have one table **client** with three column **IdPatient, keyPatient, nbvisits**
and I have a table **logclient** with 3 column **IdPatient, keyPatient, date**

I need to group by [IdPatient], [keyPatient] and to count logs on the table logclient

```
 SELECT [IdPatient],[keyPatient], count(*) 
 FROM [dbo].[logclient ]
 group by [IdPatient], [keyPatient]
```

and after I need to extract records on table **client** that have nbvisits different for my previous count(*) (I can have no client records too on table client).

How can I do it please with one query?

**Table client**

```
    | IdPatient| keyPatient |nbvisits
    |----------|---         |
    |    18569 | 3          |1
    |    18571 | 2          |1
    |    20000 | 0          |2
```

**Table LogClient**

```
    | IdPatient | keyPatient |date
    |---------- |---         |
    |    18569  | 3          |1990
    |    18571  | 2          |1990
    |    18571  | 2          |1990
    |    20000  | 0          |1990
    |    20000  | 0          |1990
    |    200001 | 2          |1990
```

after my groupby IdPatient and KeyPatient and count

```
 SELECT [IdPatient],[keyPatient], count(*) 
 FROM [dbo].[logclient]
 group by [IdPatient], [keyPatient]
```

I have

```
    | IdPatient | keyPatient |count
    |---------- |---         |
    |    18569  | 3          |1
    |    18571  | 2          |2
    |    20000  | 0          |2
    |    200001 | 2          |1
```

Now I need to check with the first table **CLIENT** if count<>nbvisites and to have lines where my count different from nbvisits

Final result:

```
    | IdPatient | keyPatient |count
    |---------- |---         |
    |    18571  | 2          |2
    |    200001 | 2          |1
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve].

Comment: i try to make a sample on the first post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your query up as a *derived table* (the subquery). Use `EXISTS` to see if there exist a client row with same IdPatient value, but other count.

```
select dt.*
from
(
    SELECT [IdPatient], [keyPatient], count(*) cnt
    FROM [dbo].[logclient ]
    group by [IdPatient], [keyPatient]
) dt
where exists (select * from client c
              where dt.[IdPatient] = c.[IdPatient]
                and dt.cnt <> c.[nbvisits])
```

To return rows that doesn't have client row with same count:

```
select dt.*
from
(
    SELECT [IdPatient], [keyPatient], count(*) cnt
    FROM [dbo].[logclient ]
    group by [IdPatient], [keyPatient]
) dt
where not exists (select * from client c
                  where dt.[IdPatient] = c.[IdPatient]
                    and dt.cnt = c.[nbvisits])
```

Comment: seems ok  bit if i have lines on the group by and not not on client, i will not have it in lastresult like this one  |    200001 | 2          |1

Comment: This query produces the result you specified, having your data. But I'll give you an alternative query that maybe suits you better. Check back in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm just missing last record on the result because theres no client with the IdPatient 200001  | keyPatient 2